# Verb conjugation in bullet lists

Tags: verbs, lists

I have a bullet list and each item has a description. Please, see the verb conjugation in the options below.

**Option A:**

- Clone: Duplicate the post.
- New Draft: Duplicate the post and open the new clone.

**Option B:**

- Clone: DuplicateS the post.
- New Draft: DuplicateS the post and openS the new clone.

Are both options grammatically correct? What is the preferred usage?

Comment: By putting it after the colon, duplicates is like a sentence that says: A clone duplicates the post. By not using the verb, you are putting it in the imperative. And as telling a clone to duplicate a post makes no sense, that should tell you which to use....

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your response. Yes, I suspected that "Clone: Duplicates the post" was the preferred choice for the reasons you said, but I am still in doubt about the other option. It is a list, and for each item, we are providing a description. We are not saying that <phrase before the colon> must do <phrase after the colon>. At least in my native language (Spanish), both options are perfectly OK. It is a matter of style. [OPTION A] (SP) Clonar: Duplicar el post. => (EN) Clone: Duplicate the post /// [OPTION B] (SP) Clonar: Duplica el post => (EN) Clone => Duplicates the post.

Comment: I frequently write bullet lists of actions like this, and I normally use the uninflected form of the verb ("duplicate the post", etc). Although it looks like an imperative, I'm not sure that it is. It's almost like the argument of an implicit modal verb (the different options will, respectively, 1: duplicate the post; 2: duplicate the post and open the new clone). Regardless of how it's analysed, I'd say this form is common in technical writing, and just as correct.

Comment: Close: Duplicated post